# Pandas: cumulative sum every n rows

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with a column "date" of type dtype M8[ns] and another "expected_response". Then, there is a column "cumulative_expected" which does the cumulative sum of the expected_response among the rows with the same date. The dataframe has a row for each second of the month. Like below:

```
               date Expected_response cumulative_expected
       0    2018-03-01  0.270   0.270
       1    2018-03-01  0.260   0.530
       2    2018-03-01  0.240   0.770
       3    2018-03-01  0.224   0.994
       4    2018-03-01  0.204   1.198
       5    2018-03-01  0.194   1.392
       6    2018-03-01  0.190   1.582
       ...  ...     ...     ...
2678395     2018-03-31  0.164   -7533.464
2678396     2018-03-31  0.164   -7533.300
2678397     2018-03-31  0.160   -7533.140
2678398     2018-03-31  0.154   -7532.986
2678399     2018-03-31  0.150   -7532.836
```

as you can see there is an error: the cumulative sum does not recognise the Change of the date and the cumulative sum does not restart each time the date changes.

The code is:

`df['cumulative_expected']=df.groupby(df['date']!=df['date'])['Expected_response'].cumsum()`

Maybe an Option could be to create a Counter that increases by 1 each 86400 rows (seconds in a day) and then groupby the Counter. But I don't know how to do it.

Is there any other solution?
thank you in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is default index, so you can use floor division:

```
df['cumulative_expected'] = df['Expected_response'].groupby(df.index // 86400).cumsum()
```

Generally solution is create `np.arange` with floor division:

```
arr = np.arange(len(df)) // 86400
df['cumulative_expected'] = df['Expected_response'].groupby(arr).cumsum()
```

Your solution should be changed with comparing [`shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.shift.html)ed values with [`cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.cumsum.html):

```
s = (df['date']!=df['date'].shift()).cumsum()
df['cumulative_expected'] = df['Expected_response'].groupby(s).cumsum()
```

Test with changed sample data:

```
print (df)

         date  Expected_response
0  2018-03-01              0.270
1  2018-03-01              0.260
2  2018-03-02              0.240
3  2018-03-02              0.224
4  2018-03-02              0.204
5  2018-03-01              0.194
6  2018-03-01              0.190

s = (df['date']!=df['date'].shift()).cumsum()
print (s)
0    1
1    1
2    2
3    2
4    2
5    3
6    3
Name: date, dtype: int32

df['cumulative_expected'] = df['Expected_response'].groupby(s).cumsum()
print (df)
        date  Expected_response  cumulative_expected
0 2018-03-01              0.270                0.270
1 2018-03-01              0.260                0.530
2 2018-03-02              0.240                0.240
3 2018-03-02              0.224                0.464
4 2018-03-02              0.204                0.668
5 2018-03-01              0.194                0.194
6 2018-03-01              0.190                0.384
```

Answer (score 2):

You can take the first difference of the date using [`diff`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.diff.html) to see were the changes occur, and use this as a reference to take the cumulative sum.
Here I use a slightly modified `df` to see how works:

```
print(df)

     date          Expected_response  
0 2018-03-01              0.270                
1 2018-03-01              0.260                
2 2018-03-01              0.240                
3 2018-03-01              0.224               
4 2018-03-02              0.204                 
5 2018-03-02              0.194                
6 2018-03-02              0.190                

df['change'] = df.date.diff().abs().fillna(0).cumsum()
print(df)

    date    Expected_response   change
0 2018-03-01              0.270 0 days
1 2018-03-01              0.260 0 days
2 2018-03-01              0.240 0 days
3 2018-03-01              0.224 0 days
4 2018-03-02              0.204 1 days
5 2018-03-02              0.194 1 days
6 2018-03-02              0.190 1 days

df['cumulative_expected'] = df.groupby('change').cumsum()
print(df.drop(['change'], axis = 1))

    date          Expected_response  cumulative_expected
0 2018-03-01              0.270                0.270
1 2018-03-01              0.260                0.530
2 2018-03-01              0.240                0.770
3 2018-03-01              0.224                0.994
4 2018-03-02              0.204                0.204
5 2018-03-02              0.194                0.398
6 2018-03-02              0.190                0.588
```